# How does position absolute plus all four directions at 0 center an inner element?

Tags: css, layout, centering

I'm reviewing some code and while it works, I do not understand how the CSS below is centering the inner div.

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/aaron/pen/awnKd) available too.

HTML

```
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.outer .inner {
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: The full container and inner is controlling the boxes dimension with absolute and then the margin is controlling the alignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason a colleague at work doesn't want the sweet SO points so here is his answer.

If you were to put

```
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

on a normal div without height or width it would make the div the entire size of its container. Putting `height` and `width` on that div would constrain it and while it would try to fill its container, it would respect the set dimensions.

Setting `margin: auto;` as mentioned is the key. This allows the box for this div to fill its container by expanding the margins equally while respecting its set dimensions.

Is this the best way to center things? No idea but it works.

Answer (score 1):

it is just because of

```
 margin: auto;
```

You can get better understanding of this from [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer for you question.

The `margin: auto` just tells the browser to split up the available space evenly between the left and right side of the element. By available space, any unoccupied horizontal space between the left and right edges of the parent container.

[Reference](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=33525)